# Opposite of epicanthic fold (not occidental)

Tags: nouns, adjectives, terminology, image-identification

There are families that have a *certain genetic marker of the eyes*, looking more or less like the opposite of the epicanthic fold of Asian eyes. I have seen it in some Native Americans and some people of French descent.

[image]

If you look at the outer and upper corners of this Native American  girl’s eyes, you will see it.

[image]

The royal family also has this. It is not common, and is a marker in my (native american) family. The older one gets, the more pronounced it becomes, and it tends to droop in the upper corners of the eyes.
What is this called?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61880/discussion-on-question-by-cascabel-opposite-of-epicanthic-fold-not-occidental).

Comment: I have this trait, but I wish people would stop using the term “oriental.” When used in reference to people, it is considered racist.

Comment: @Bob I have changed the 'offensive" term to _asian_.

Comment: @Bob: Note that that is, to some extent, a regional thing (eg a British friend of Asian origin related an occasion where he described himself as "oriental" to an American, who told him he "shouldn't do himself down like that"; this was a surprise to my friend as to him it was a purely geographical term!). I'm not saying the term shouldn't be avoided (it does offend plenty of people, and there are good alternatives that aren't offensive), just be aware that people using it may not intend any offence.

Comment: By 'opposite' you don't mean the negative of the meaning, but rather locationally on the other side of the eye? Nasal for the usual meaning and lateral for the outside, on the other side away from the nose? (there's gotta be official medical terms for those two but I can't seem to remember)

Comment: @Mitch I posted a self-answer on this and it includes those medical terms you cite.

Comment: @Cascabel I see now.

Comment: TXS @Mitch It made me realize that I screwed up a little on the post. I got sloppy, but I think it's better now for your kind attention.  9K views....who woulda thunk it? I completely forgot about this post!

Comment: @Cascabel 'medial' and 'lateral' on re-reading yours, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is still called an ***epicanthic fold***.

***[Canthus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canthus)*** refers to the “corners” of the eye. There is the [medial (or internal),  canthus; and the  lateral (or external), canthus.](http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Lateral_canthus)
[image]

*Epi*, [meaning over or above](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=epi), can be used with *canthus* to indicate a covering of the corner of the eye.
More accurately, this particular facial aspect can be called a ***lateral*** (or external) ***canthal fold***, or simply an ***external epicanthus***.

However (and unsurprisingly), there is also a cosmetology term to describe this feature.

***Downturned***, as seen in [these guides to eye makeup](https://www.google.com/search?q=hooded%20eyes&client=firefox-b&tbm=isch&imgil=lDZ8KdbjFDMrzM%253A%253BIYFiC-o_65hDLM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.buzzfeed.com%25252Fchrissymahlmeister%25252Fhooded-eye-makeup&source=iu&pf=m&fir=lDZ8KdbjFDMrzM%253A%252CIYFiC-o_65hDLM%252C_&usg=__JJSG6NDQ7hT7B3Yecw88y8RRNyk%3D&biw=1024&bih=585&ved=0ahUKEwji1bDC4MrUAhWMwiYKHT4SCVcQyjcISg&ei=1zRIWaKOGoyFmwG-pKS4BQ#tbm=isch&q=downturned%20%20eyes&imgrc=7_Kblbo49K878M:) from different manufacturers.

[image]

I also saw the terms "droopy" and "puppy dog" eyes to describe this.

Comment: I now know more about makeup for specific eye types than I ever thought I would need in this lifetime.

Comment: Recently, there has been some controversy over the usage of the term  "fox" eyes and its appropriation by occidental people.

Answer (score 4):

I use the term "outer epicanthic folds" for myself and my northern English family.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. While half of my family comes also from Northern England and Ireland, the other half is Native American, and I have never been sure which side of the family this characteristic comes from. Actually, still not sure.